# TFS Release - Pre and Post Approval Update

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have around 200 applications/services build/release under TFS 2018. Under TFS release we have TEST/QA/PROD pipelines and pre and post approver setup for each environment. One of approver leaving organization and we have to replace his name with new personal name in all 200 release definitions. If we start updating them manually we have to open and edit all 200 release definitions and update one by one. Is there any way i can update all 200 release definition and change/replace approver name?

Comment: Have you investigated using the REST APIs to update your release definitions?

Answer (score 0):

So in general I would aim for using Groups as approvers instead of having the names of the approvers directly in the release definition. With that approach, you can just create different groups and add/remove people in those groups, which will affect all the release definitions wihtout having them to edit manually.

In case you have completly different approvers for all of the 200 release definitions of course this does only shift the problem, as then you would need to update all the groups manually. But if we have mainly the same users I think that is your best option.

Now of course in order to update the release definitions initally from having the manually defined names to the groups you would still need to go through all of the 200 definitions and edit them, however this would be a one time thing, afterwards everything would be configured via the groups. You might even get the removal of a person for free, as they should be removed from a group automatically if the user is removed.

If you cannot use groups or you really have completly different approvers everywhere, it might be worth looking into the REST APIs ([Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/?view=vsts-rest-4.1)) and create a custom script/tool that automates the job tailored to your needs.